# Why is a CoreML image segmentation model with significantly reduced input image dimensions no faster than the original model?

Tags: tensorflow, coreml

I am building an iPhone app with a vision processing component that could use image segmantation, especially if it can run at 30fps.  I am starting the exploration process with [this repo](https://github.com/tucan9389/SemanticSegmentation-CoreML), which uses [the 8bit model from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/).  The inference times I get on an iPhone 7 are on the order of 200ms on 513x513 images.

I am used to image models scaling linearly with the number of pixels, so I assumed if I changed the size of the input image to 320x240 (the size we eventually expect to use) then I would get a speed up factor of 513x513/(320x240), for inference times around 60ms.  However, the inference time is still on the order of 200ms.

Further detail: I created the 320x240 model by starting with the [Deep Lab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug from the [Deep Lab Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md) and then used coremltools to convert it to a CoreML model with input size 320x240 and quantized to 8 bits using kmeans.

Does anyone have any insight into why I am not seeing a speedup?  Is there some way to achieve the throughput I was expecting?